# Loop vectorisation in Python

Tags: python, numeric, numerical-methods, ode

I am trying to vectorize a Python `for` loop, but I am experiencing a problem.
I am dealing with a first-order explicit Euler discretization of a simple ordinary differential equation (namely, speed is the time-derivative of position), reading
[image: First-order explicit Euler]

I tried a `loop` version of this equation, as shown in the code below (the first column of `x_t` store the x-axis position, while the second column stores the y-axis position), and everything works just fine (`t` is the time vector, `x0` the initial position along the x- and y-axis, `v_t` the x- and y-components of the speed, and `dt` is the time increment).

```
len_t = len(t)
x_t = np.zeros( (len_t, 2) )

x_t[0, 0] = x0[0]
x_t[0, 1] = x0[1]

for idx in range(1, len_t):
    x_t[idx, 0] = x_t[idx-1, 0] + v_t[idx-1, 0] * dt
    x_t[idx, 1] = x_t[idx-1, 1] + v_t[idx-1, 1] * dt
```

When I try to vectorize the above code by writing

```
len_t = len(t)
x_t = np.zeros( (len_t, 2) )

x_t[0, 0] = x0[0]
x_t[0, 1] = x0[1]

x_t[1:, 0] = x_t[:-1, 0] + v_t[:-1, 0] * dt
x_t[1:, 1] = x_t[:-1, 1] + v_t[:-1, 1] * dt
```

no correct result is computed (the components of `v_t` where also computed via a `for` loop). Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You cannot vectorize if each value depends on the previous value. You can only vectorize if you have many independent x and v values. Then you can update them all once per time step.

Comment: You probably can speed up the loop overhead using some version of JIT (e.g., numba). It does not support all numpy constructs, but should be enough for numerical ODE integration. Also, you can use vector operations, `x_t[idx] = x_t[idx-1] + v_t[idx-1] * dt` does the same as the two component-wise lines. Cumulative sums have a numpy command `cumsum`, but that does not work when you start to solve proper ODE where `v_t[i]` is computed from `x_t[i]`.